# comparing two arrays, increasing counter

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, pass-by-value

I'm having problems realizing why my counter keeps printing out a different value even when I enter all the right answers. I've tried everything I could think of plus researching and still no luck. Please help, this is hour 14 of me working on this "simple" program.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner

public class DriverTestBlah {
 public static void main(String [] args){

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  char[] correctAnswers = {'A','D','C','A','A','D','B',
  'A','C','A','D','C','B','A','B'};
  char singleAnswer = ' ';
  int number_Correct = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) //print question numbers/takes user input
          {
      System.out.println("Question " + (i + 1) + ":");
         singleAnswer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
          }//end of for loop

   System.out.println("number correct: " +
        total_correct_answers(correctAnswers, singleAnswer));
  }//end of main

  public static int total_correct_answers(char []correctAnswers,char singleAnswer){
      int number_correct = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
         if(correctAnswers[i] == singleAnswer){
             number_correct++;}

        }//end of for loop
    return number_correct;
    }//end of correct method
  }//end of class
```

Comment: You should add what the program is doing and give examples of the expected output and the results you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your program was showing wrong value is `singleAnswer` variable stores only the last value/answer given by user.

I have created an array `userAnswer` to store all answers given.

Try this:

```
public class DriverTestBlah {
  public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] correctAnswers = {'A','D','C','A','A','D','B',
    'A','C','A','D','C','B','A','B'};
    char[] userAnswer = new char[correctAnswers.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) //print question numbers/takes user input
    {
      System.out.println("Question " + (i + 1) + ":");
      userAnswer [i] = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    }//end of for loop

    System.out.println("number correct: " + total_correct_answers(correctAnswers, userAnswer));

    input.close();
  }//end of main

  public static int total_correct_answers(char []correctAnswers,char [] userAnswer) {
    int number_correct = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        if(correctAnswers[i] == userAnswer[i]){
            number_correct++;
        }
    }//end of for loop
    return number_correct;
  }//end of correct method
}//end of class
```

Comment: Thank y'all so much, you have no idea how stressful this was for me. I actually understand what i did wrong:)

Answer (score 0):

For every question you have the correct answers in the array **correctAnswers** and user-answer where? In this mode in *singleAnswer* you save only the last answer of user and check it for every answer.
To solve this problem you can create an array of char of singleAnswer like that:

```
char[] singleAnswer=new char[15];
```

And the result add in the array:

```
singleAnswer[i]=input.nextLine().chatAt(0);
```

After you can see if the result is correct with this instruction in the for loop:

```
if(singleAnswer[i]==correctAnswers[i])  number_correct++;
```